# how can I find out the ASCII code of a character in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Does anybody know how to find out the ascii code of a character in gnuplot?

There is no official function to do that, so it must probably be some kind of trick.

(OK, i found a way, answer directly below)

Answer (score 3):

In lieu of an `ord(ch)` function, one can build a string with all characters, and find the position of the one in question using the `strstrt()`function.

```
# make a string that contains all ASCII chars from 1 to 255
ALLCHARS = ''; do for [i=1:255] {ALLCHARS = ALLCHARS.sprintf('%c',i)}
# return position of character in ALLCHARS if ch contains 1 char, -1 otherwise
ord(ch) = (strlen(ch) == 1) ? strstrt(ALLCHARS,ch): -1

# test with ASCII char 12
pr n=12, testch = sprintf('%c',n), ord(testch)
```

The NUL (ASCII-code zero) character is missing, because gnuplot anyway has no single character variable type that could hold it. gnuplot strings are NUL terminated.

Comment: Good idea to create such an ASCII string as lookup using `sprintf("%c",n)`. In the past (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54150791/7295599), I used a constant string which did not include the non-printable characters and characters from 128-255. You code works fine if you change two mistakes: `do for [i=1:255] ...` and `ord(ch) = (strlen(ch) == 1 )? strstrt(ALLCHARS,ch): -1`

Comment: @theozh Thanks, no idea how those two crept back in, sure had them out of the test script on my computer ... ;-)