# How to fix this gnuplot error to handle key presses?

Tags: keyboard, gnuplot, mouse, numeric

I'm trying to provide basic keyboard interaction for my gnuplot script.
With `gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 1` I'm using MOUSE_CHAR as [documented](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/mouse-input.html), I believe, however with the simplest script below, I get an error no matter what key I press.

```
while (1) {
    pause mouse keypress
    show variable MOUSE_

    if (exists("MOUSE_CHAR")) {
        if (MOUSE_CHAR == "w") {
            print "w"
        }
    }             # <-- line 114

    replot
}
```

The output shows the correct key pressed, for example:

```
        MOUSE_KEY = 119
        MOUSE_CHAR = "w"
```

or

```
        MOUSE_KEY = 114
        MOUSE_CHAR = "r"
```

But immediately after I get

```
"hrtp.gp" line 114: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for string equality is `eq` not `==`, so you want `if (MOUSE_CHAR eq "w") { print "w" }`.

Comment: You saved me from doing this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312933/1088790