# Display label on gnuplot value in heatmap

Tags: matrix, gnuplot, heatmap

Base on gnuplot example about "Heat map with non-zero pixel values written as labels" in here:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/heatmaps.html

I have data:

```
6 5 4 3 1 0
3 2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 2 3
0 0 1 2 4 4
0 1 2 3 4 6
```

and my gnuplot:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 500, 350 
set output 'heatmaps.png'

unset key
set view map
set xtics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set ytics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set ztics border in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set nocbtics
set rtics axis in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set xrange [ -0.500000 : 4.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ -0.500000 : 4.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 5.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set palette rgbformulae -7, 2, -7
splot 'heatmap.txt' matrix using 1:2:3 with image, \
      'heatmap.txt' matrix using 1:2:($3 == 0 ? " " : sprintf("$3") ) with labels
```

this script just printout "3" in every labels. Could you help me? thanks

and also label for Xtics and Ytics

```
 Tipe1 Tipe2 Tipe3 Tipe4 Tipe5
Failure1 6 2 0 0 1
Failure2 0 0 0 1 0
Failure3 0 0 0 2 3
Failure4 0 1 2 4 4
Failure5 1 2 3 4 6
```

Thanks again

Comment: You have almost exactly copied the script you linked, and changed only that part which now gives you troubles... hmm ;)

Comment: Thanks for advice @Christoph. Yes, I will be take care about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the wrong call to the sprintf function.

```
sprintf(format,values)
```

You should call sprintf with a decimal number in format (`%d`) and the label value you want to display (third column `$3`) :

```
sprintf("%d",$3)
```

I copied your data into a file (named `data`) and this example works well :

```
plot 'data' matrix using 1:2:3 with image, '' matrix using 1:2:($3==0 ? " " : sprintf("%d",$3)) with labels
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's correct, I missed sprintf("%d",$3).

onemore thing, 

how to change the Xtics and Ytics label?

6 5 4 3 1 0
3 2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 2 3
0 0 1 2 4 4
0 1 2 3 4 6

Comment: @indi60 Could you be more precise: What do you mean with the xtic and ytic labels?

Comment: I mean labels in X axis and Y axis.
I found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795974/gnuplot-label-x-and-y-axis-of-matrix-heatmap-with-row-and-column-names) related with my question.

but the example is not use matrix. anysuggestion for this?

Comment: You can set pre-defined tics by the following : set xtics ("Tipe1" 0,"Tipe2" 1,"Tipe3" 2, "Tipe4" 3, "Tipe5" 4)

Comment: @indi60 Actually, the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10799204/2604213 works fine for me with the data file you posted.

Comment: Solves everything. Thanks @Pascail