# gnuplot: with x and y-axis label (rowstacked) with row and column names

Tags: graph, gnuplot, stacked-chart

I haven't answer the question after I google it.

I have data.txt like this:

```
     a b c
sys1 3 2 0
sys2 4 4 4
sys3 5 2 4
sys4 6 4 1
```

I created graphs using rowstacked style with pattern, currently I select the patterns manually. I have to plotting my data.txt with sys1-sys4 and a-c. This matrix always have the same size, but I should do sorting and re generate with different order sequence.

this is my gnuplot script:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set key invert reverse right outside # above outside  or left outside
set boxwidth 0.75


set ylabel "Count"
set xlabel "System"
set xtics nomirror rotate by -270
set output 'eps/a1-count.eps'
plot 'a1-count' \
    using($2):xtic(1)   title "data 1" lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($3)           title "data 2" lt -1 fs pattern 4, \
''  using($3)           title "data 3" lt -1 fs pattern 6
```

and this is the output:
[image]

I also found some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795974/gnuplot-label-x-and-y-axis-of-matrix-heatmap-with-row-and-column-names) but it is for heat map. Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. How should the resulting image look like? Do you want 'a' etc as key entries, or something else?

Comment: @Christoph I have to make the label dynamic. because somehow I  sorting the data. the order can be [sys3, sys4, sys2, sys1], depends on the data. Do you get my point?

Comment: Well, the xticklabels are dynamic. But you are also talking about the column names... Do you want them to be used as legend entries?

Comment: @Christoph: yes, because my actual data is does not have legend entries.
as my script:
    using($2):xtic(1)   title "data 1" lt -1 fs pattern 3, \

I used title "data 1" (not from table data). 
but in this condition, I also want to order the patterns statis.
i.e:
first column use pattern 3, second column use pattern 6, etc.

any idea about this @Christoph?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort directly the data within gnuplot : (-nk[column]), with linux 'sort' command:

```
plot '<sort -nk1 data.txt'  \
    u 2:xtic(1)   title "data 1" lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  u 3           title "data 2" lt -1 fs pattern 4, \
''  u 3           title "data 3" lt -1 fs pattern 6
```

The '' empty string file call, will keep the sorted datafile.

the title of your question is not correct, but thanks to you, i learnd the :xtic(column) feature and the correct way of doing :
set xtics nomirror rotate by -270

Regards,